# Shorter, easier and more effective way of saving data?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Thanks to this great community, I managed to make a save system for my game! However, it is kind of long and painful to write. I need help on how to (if possible) make this a little bit shorter and easier.

So, this is what I got (this example uses ONLY 1 variable to get the idea):

```
GameState = loadsave.loadTable("GameState.json")

if GameState == nil then
    GameState = {
        TotalPixoosGS = 0,
    }

    loadsave.saveTable(GameState, "GameState.json")
end

TotalPixoos = GameState.TotalPixoosGS
```

Let me quickly explain what I got here: `GameState = loadsave.loadTable("GameState.json")` is declaration of a table from .json file. I used .loadTable function which I got from here:

https://code.coronalabs.com/code/easy-saveload-table-data-corona-sdk

```
if GameState == nil then
        GameState = {
            TotalPixoosGS = 0,
        }
```

If the file doesn't exist, it simply creates default game settings, in this case sets `TotalPixoosGS` variable to value of `0`.

```
loadsave.saveTable(GameState, "GameState.json")
```

Again a function from the link above which simply creates .json file from `GameState` table, calls it `GameState.json`.

```
TotalPixoos = GameState.TotalPixoosGS
```

Finally, assigns the value of `GameState.TotalPixoosGS` to our variable `TotalPixoos` (if `GameState.json` doesn't exist, it will assign the value of `0`). So far, pretty straight-forward, right?

Now, this code was called upon OPENING the application.

The following code is what I use upon EXITING application:

```
if ( event.type == "applicationExit" ) then
      GameState = {
            TotalPixoosGS = TotalPixoos,
      }

      loadsave.saveTable(GameState, "GameState.json")
end
```

Basically, what this does is: When the app is about to exit, you simply change the value of `TotalPixoosGS` to our current value of `TotalPixoos` (that is the variable which changes over time). Finally, we save the `GameState` table with the new, changed `TotalPixoosGS`.

Once the app launches again, the process will repeat.

Now, what is the problem? Well, when you have 1 variable, like in this case, it looks simple. However, when you gotta manage over 50 variables, it can be a pain to write. Is there any way I could shorten this?

Anyway, this is just a small chunk of code, to get the idea:

```
GameState = loadsave.loadTable("GameState.json")


if GameState == nil then
    GameState = {
        TotalPixoosGS = 0,
        PixoosQuantityGS = 0,
        PixoosPerSecondGS = 0,

        BottlesQuantityGS = 0,
        MaxBottlesFoundGS = 0,
        BottlesPriceGS = 0.005,
        WillFindBottlesChanceGS = 10,
        CanFindBottlesGS = 0,

        MaxClickableGS = 5,
        MaxTrashCanValueGS = 5,
    }

    loadsave.saveTable(GameState, "GameState.json")
end

TotalPixoos = GameState.TotalPixoosGS
PixoosQuantity = GameState.PixoosQuantityGS
PixoosPerSecond = GameState.PixoosPerSecondGS

BottlesQuantity = GameState.BottlesQuantityGS
MaxBottlesFound = GameState.MaxBottlesFoundGS
BottlesPrice = GameState.BottlesPriceGS
WillFindBottlesChance = GameState.WillFindBottlesChanceGS
CanFindBottles = GameState.CanFindBottlesGS

MaxClickable = GameState.MaxClickableGS
MaxTrashCanValue = GameState.MaxTrashCanValueGS
```

See how much of ugly code there is? And this is upon exit:

```
if ( event.type == "applicationExit" ) then
      GameState = {
            TotalPixoosGS = TotalPixoos,
            PixoosQuantityGS = PixoosQuantity,
            PixoosPerSecondGS = PixoosPerSecond,

            BottlesQuantityGS = BottlesQuantity,
            MaxBottlesFoundGS = MaxBottlesFound,
            BottlesPriceGS = BottlesPrice,
            WillFindBottlesChanceGS = WillFindBottlesChance,
            CanFindBottlesGS = CanFindBottles,

            MaxClickableGS = MaxClickable,
            MaxTrashCanValueGS = MaxTrashCanValue,

       }

       loadsave.saveTable(GameState, "GameState.json")
end
```

Anyone with a better way, or idea on how to deal with this?

Comment: Use `GameState` the table as your toplevel global for the running game code? Instead of individual toplevel global variables?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I completely understand what are you suggesting me...

Comment: You have N global variables for your state. Your problem is that you need to stuff those in a table to save them and then pull them out to load them. If you stop using N global variables and use 1 global variable (the table itself) then you can directly load and save it and you just use `GameState.TotalPixoosGS`, `GameState.PixoosQuantityGS`, etc. in your game instead of just `TotalPixoosGS` and `PixoosQuantityGS`.

Comment: So, basically, I just use `GameState.variable` every time I need that variable?

Comment: Not "just". But yes, if you can rewrite to keep a single global table then you can just save and load that table directly instead of needing to stuff values into the table for storage and pull them out for game usage.

Comment: Why on *Earth* are you using JSON?

Comment: Before negote venturing further down this road, take a moment to read this: http://www.lua.org/pil/12.html

Comment: negote was a typo btw

Comment: @warspyking Well, I am still a beginner developer and I find this way of saving really simple, that's why.

Comment: It's actually more COMPLICATED. Please, review the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are storing the data in independent global variables that you need to store in the table to save and then fetch from the table to load.

You can avoid needing to do all of that if you just use the table itself as the global variable in your general code.

So instead of writing code that uses `TotalPixoosGS` or `PixoosQuantityGS` when checking the values/etc. you write code that uses `GameState.TotalPixoosGS` and `GameState.PixoosQuantityGS` instead and then just save and load directly from/to the global `GameState` table.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I needed to change every single variable in the game by adding prefix `GameState.`, but I managed to get it working thanks to you, sir!